# How can I get this MySql WordPress query to run faster?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, optimization, entity-attribute-value

I have the following query in WordPress running against some very large tables. Is there a way to reorganize it so it runs faster? Currently it's taking 8 seconds and that's too slow for my use case where I need to call it 600K times. The bit `wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 18` is going to be dynamic as in: `wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = category_id`

```
SELECT  `ID` AS athlete_id, `post_title` AS athlete_name, `post_name` AS athlete_slug,
        body_weight.weight, performance.speed
    FROM  `wp_posts`
    INNER JOIN  
      ( SELECT  `post_id`, `meta_value` AS weight
            FROM  `wp_postmeta`
            WHERE  (`meta_key` = 'athlete_weight')
      ) body_weight ON wp_posts.ID = body_weight.post_id
    INNER JOIN  
      ( SELECT  `post_id`, `meta_value` AS speed
            FROM  `wp_postmeta`
            WHERE  (`meta_key` = 'athlete_speed')
      ) performance ON wp_posts.ID = performance.post_id
    LEFT JOIN  wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN  wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =
                                         wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT JOIN  wp_terms ON (wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id)
    WHERE  wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
      AND  wp_posts.post_type = 'athlete'
      AND  ((wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'athletics_category'
                      AND  wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 18)
              OR  (wp_terms.term_id is null)
           );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using more than one `JOIN` subquery is especially inefficient because of the lack of an index in the tmp table.  (Yeah, 5.6 adds an index on the fly, but this is still less efficient.)

Instead, JOIN to the table, not to a subquery:

```
SELECT ...
    ms.meta_value AS speed
    ...
FROM ...
JOIN wp_postmeta AS ms
    ON ms.post_id = wp_posts.ID
```

(ditto for the other, but using a different alias)

(This is one example of why EAV schemas are a pain.)

Comment: Thanks so much! The difference is dramatic! The query is now running in 0.6 seconds...